# Calling Optional#isPresent() in single line is reported as not called

Tags: java, java-8, sonarqube, option-type, sonarqube-scan

I run SonarQube to check my code and I found a case which I don't understand the reported error.

My code is:

```
private static final int BASE_ID = 100_000_000;
private boolean isValidId(Id id) {
    return id.asInteger().isPresent() && id.asInteger().get() >= BASE_ID;
}
```

The method `asInteger` returns `Optional<Integer>`

The error that I am getting from sonarqube is 
`Call "Optional#isPresent()" before accessing the value.`
in the return line.

I understand that the code is ok as the second part of the `if` won’t get executed if the first one is false. I know that this can be solved with a `.filter(..).isPresent()` but I like it more this way.

Any ideas why would this happen?

Comment: I'd say it's just because those code inspection tools don't always work perfectly and some errors are just false positives. IF you rewrite it as `if(...)` I'm sure the error won't be reported anymore

Comment: What if second call to `id.asInteger()` would return empty `Optional`?

Comment: What about `return id.asInteger().orElse(-1) >= BASE_ID;`?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Sonarqube cannot guarantee that the two calls to `id.asInteger()` returns the same object, e.g. because multi-threading might have changed the value of `id` between the two calls, so it is correctly stating that the presence hasn't been adequately tested.

Change code to assign to a local variable first, to ensure that `isPresent()` and `get()` are called on the same object:

```
private boolean isValidId(Id id) {
    Optional<Integer> idAsInteger = id.asInteger();
    return idAsInteger.isPresent() && idAsInteger.get() >= BASE_ID;
}
```

Comment: Multi-threading isn't even needed: two calls to the same method are not guaranteed to return the same thing, and I'm not sure Sonar is able to guarantee that asInteger() is idempotent.

Comment: @Andreas excellent point, 1+, but I would completely write that as a single statement though

Comment: @JBNizet Sonar can never guaranty any properties of a method in a different class, as it can’t even guaranty that the implementation will be the same at runtime. The only exceptions would be well known (JDK) methods with a precisely defined contract or formal contracts expressed as annotations.

Answer (score 5):

You can write that as a single statement btw:

```
return id.asInteger()
         .map(x -> x >= BASE_ID)
         .orElse(false)
```

but sonar complaining is because well it's a false positive in this case.

Comment: Yes I know I can solve it with different methods, like the one I wrote in the question itself: `.filter(..).isPresent()` but I like it more the other way and want to understand why this may be happening. I mean, the isPresent() is being called...

Comment: But SonarQube can't know if each call to asInteger() returns a different value. So the second time, when you call get(), it might be an empty Optional

Comment: It is not a false positive - Sonar is completely correct to highlight this as a potential issue

Answer (score 0):

When working with Optionals you should avoid `.isPresent` and `.get` as much as possible. The use of these methods in not safer than using nulls and is against the functional spirit. Optionals are made for functional programming and for a typesafe alternative of null checks.

SonarQube has only limiteds capabilities with its analysis. It usually cannot exclude all kinds of false positives. This case is not really a problem because it is not recommended to use Optionals this way.

Comment: Not necessary. For example how would you not use `isPresent` when you want to take some action when value is not present.

Comment: @tsolakp Since Java 9 `yourOptional.ifPresentOrElse(dummy, this::someAction);`. Your point is valid, though, it is one of the *rare* (and possibly even sought-after?) cases where one may defend the use of `isPresent()`.

Comment: Yes, my intention was not to say "you must not use isPresent", but "in most cases it would be better to avoid it, if possible".

Answer (score 0):

To avoid this problem I use iterator().next() it has the same functionality that .get but it cames without the isPresent() issue!